How to design a general share process
My question is simple but not easy.
I want to define a share process $s_{i,t}$ that $\sum_i s_{i,t} =1$ at all times $t$.
Moreover, I am interested in the growth of the share processs, $g_{i,t+1}=s_{i,t+1}/s_{i,t}$.
What kind of $g$ or $s$ can satisfy that $\sum_i s_{i,t} =1$?

By definition, given $\sum_{i}s_{i,1} = 1$, the necessary and sufficient condition for $\sum_{i}s_{i,t} = 1$  for all $t\ge 2$ is that
$$\sum_{i}g_{i,t+1}\cdot s_{i,t} = 1 \qquad \forall t\ge 2$$

This is very true... but it is too general... is there some example distribution that g needs to follow to generate this...

@fincecon the condition is already the necessary and sufficient condition, so the answer is already exhaustive. Besides, to determine the distribution of $g_{\cdot, t+1}$ , it suffices to solve $$\cases{\sum_{i\in \mathcal{I}}g_{i,t+1}\cdot s_{i,t} = 1 \ \sum_{i\in \mathcal{I}}g_{i,t+1}= 1}\tag{}$$ and there are many distributions satisfying this if $\text{card}( \mathcal{I}) >2 $.
For the case $\text{card}( \mathcal{I}) =2 $, you can solve easily $()$.

Wow... I understand these conditions but I dont think I understand how to derive the distribution of $g$. Could you kindly provide an example? By the way, why does it require $\sum_{i} g_{i,t+1}=1$.

Sorry, we don't need to have $\sum_{i}g_{i,t+1} = 1$. And here is an example:
$$g_{i,t+1} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{s_{i,t}} \hspace{1cm} \forall i=1,..,n$$
then the condition is satisfied
$$\sum_{i=1}^n g_{i,t+1}s_{i,t} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} = 1$$
With that, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n s_{i,t+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n g_{i,t+1}s_{i,t} = 1$$

Wonderful thanks for providing the example!

I wonder if it is possible to make $g$ time-series stochastic. For example, would it be possible to make $g_{i,t+1}=\beta_{i} \varepsilon_{t+1}+\eta_{i,t+1}$, where $\varepsilon_{t+1}$ and $\eta_{i,t+1}$ are standard normal and iid.
